# Gitlab runner job is stalling on cucumber test failure

Tags: cucumber, gitlab-ci, jobs, gitlab-ci-runner, acceptance-testing

I am new to gitlab runner and trying to setup acceptance_stage after unit test passes.
The tests run on a windows machine when the job is triggered.
The job exits when tests pass, but the job stalls when test fails. I have only 1 test right now and I am planning to run multiple tests in parallel when this issue is fixed.
The test is triggered using maven command. (I have tweaked the test in such a way so that it fails.)The test fails on this command :
**mvn verify -P rest-test-run -Denvironment="qa" -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="C:\tools\chromedriver.exe"**
and the job stalls and is unable to execute the next command.
Here is the sample yaml file that i am using to trigger acceptance stage:

```
stages:
  - test
acceptance_tests:
  stage: test
  tags:
    - playground
  only:
    - ci_cd_test
  before_script:
    - export POM_VERSION=$(mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -q -DforceStdout)
    - cd ..
    - git clone "git@gitlab.<project>" "<automation project name>" 2> /dev/null || (cd "<automation project name>" ; git pull)
    - cd <webapp project name>
    - export DB_URL=jdbc url
    - export DB_USER=username
    - export DB_PASSWORD=password
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
  script:
    #    flyway migrates
    - java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar <webapp project name>/target/<webapp project name>-$POM_VERSION.jar flyway migrate
    #    Bring up the app
    - ./start.sh
    #    Run cucumber test
    - cd ../<automation project name>
    - mvn verify -P rest-test-run -Denvironment="qa" -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="C:\tools\chromedriver.exe"
    - cd ../<webapp project name>
    #    Stop the app
    - ./stop.sh
```

I have also attached a screen shot of the stalling job.

[image: stalling job image on test failure]

Some troubleshooting ideas that I tried implementing:

1. upgraded surefireplugin(the version that I use in 2.22.0)
2. added a cleanup_job in yaml file
3. ran tests not in parallel
   the above ideas did not solve the problem.

Comment: Have you tried breaking down the pipeline such that the webapp start, selenium tests, webapp stop are in different stages?

Comment: Yes the yml file has different stages for starting the app, running the test and stopping the app. Script stage, acceptance_test stage and clean_up stage.

Comment: Thank you this got resolved. I saved the maven exit code and used it as my final exit code. I will close this issue.